# UniswapV2 swapExactETHForTokens method fails with error status 'UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED'

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, uniswap

I am using web3.js library and I am trying to buy a token by calling swapExactETHForTokens method from
[UniswapV2Router02 smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d), but I don't know why my transaction fails. I approved WETH for this transaction, but still get an error with the following status:

> Fail with error 'UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED'

My code:

```
const swapTokens = async () => {
  const PRIVATE_KEY = 'my private key goes here';

  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(PRIVATE_KEY);

  const myAccount = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0].address;

  const WETHAddress = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2';
  const swapRouterAddress = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D';

  const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER_ABI,
    swapRouterAddress,
  );

  const tokenToBuyAddress = '0x0913dDAE242839f8995c0375493f9a1A3Bddc977';
  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20;

  const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  const gasLimit = Math.round(block.gasLimit / block.transactions.length);

  const amountToBuy = 0.01;

  const result = await routerContract.methods
    .swapExactETHForTokens(
      web3.utils.toHex(0),
      [WETHAddress, tokenToBuyAddress],
      myAccount,
      deadline,
    )
    .send({
      from: myAccount,
      gasLimit,
      value: web3.utils.toWei(`${amountToBuy}`, 'ether'),
    });

  console.log('result: ', result);
}

swapTokens();
```

Transaction details on etherscan: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4c6f507ed95b2889bdb929a34dbbe0114db168c2462ce21778eeed9dc4a894eb

Smart contract of token which I am trying to buy: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0913dDAE242839f8995c0375493f9a1A3Bddc977#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction ran out of gas. Increase your gas limit

[image]